# How to hide the contents of index page, in angularjs ng-view

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, ng-view, ng-hide

I am trying to find whether I can hide the parent file contents when accessing a partial(view) in angularJs. Here is my problem:
I have my parent page (index page) with contents like menubar, footer and some other stuff which will be displayed in all the pages in my product. I have included ng-view in between the stuff and the footer. Now, in a particular page, I don't want to show this menubar, footer. I need to show only that particular stuff which is present in the partial. So, I need to hide the menubar, footer and all other stuff which is from parent scope. Is it possible to do it with angularJS?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

you can set a `$rootScope` variable that says whether to display menu or not (according the route)

```
// particular route controller
$rootScope.hideMenu = true;
```

and then in the markup add

```
ng-hide="hideMenu"
```

to any element you want not to display